# When should I start soft resetting for female fossil Pokémon in Sun?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I bought the skull and cover fossils and I wanna know if it's possible to soft rest for female when you revive the fossil?

And if I save before I buy the fossils and before I revive the fossils will it make any difference?

Comment: Honestly, there's no real use for females any more, except flavor. And since you're probably going to breed anyway to get better stats, you might as well target a female then. Any other gender-related things (except determining the species in non-ditto cross species breeding) have been removed: moves, hidden abilities and balls are all passed down by both males and females now.

Answer (score 3):

You can soft-reset just before reviving the fossil to get different gender. It is not determined when you buy the fossil.

I recommend saving right before talking to the NPC at the fossil restoration center (reviving the fossil) to reduce the time between attempts.

Stating this from personal experience, but this was also the case in [previous games](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67483141).